How do I find which "system software from developer" is blocked?
This is a similar problem as How to find Software by developer on a Mac (System software from developer was blocked from loading) but the answers posted there don't work for me because this developer isn't listed in the places it is suggested to look.
Problem
In macOS Settings > Privacy & Security there is some blocked software from "Samsung Electronics":

I want to figure out what piece of software is being blocked.
Attempts
I tried greping the recommended Extensions directories for "electronics" and got nothing ("Samsung" just yields AppleSamsung extensions).
I tried looking at "Obtained from" in System Information as suggested, but that just says "Identified Developer" not the developer's name:

Update 20241209
Per @Yorik's clever suggestion, I tried iterating through the code signatures with some help from Claude.
for app in /Applications/*.app; do
  certificate=$(codesign -dvv --deep "$app" 2>&1 | grep -Eo 'Authority=.+' | head -n 1 | cut -d'=' -f2-)
  if [[ "$certificate" == *"Samsung"* ]]; then
    echo "$app"
  fi
done

I got no results for "Samsung," but substituting in other names (e.g. "Apple") does yield results.
Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

I don't use a mac, but I note that the developer name will probably be emitted in the "signed by" field if you drill down per app. A quick search suggest that there is a native mac tool called codesign which may be useful along with grep but the trick is iterating the list (assuming the tool won't take wildcards). see, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057472/how-to-text-match-the-specific-line-in-codesign-so-as-to-check-whether-its-signe

I don't have enough reputation to comment ... why would you need to comment on another question?

Welcome to Superuser. Having a different question is OK. Creating a new question to highlight a different question and then promising to close your new question is not OK. Please read the Help section, understand how this site works, and then work within the rules and norms to get your problems solved the way this site allows that to be done.

Thanks @music2myear. I'll revise my question so it's distinct from the original one.
